# WSO2IS/APIM: How to assign user role in a custom authenticator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am trying to implement a custom authenticator for using with WSO2-IS and WSO2-APIM. However, I can not find a way to assign a role to the authenticated user.

I want the authenticated user to have role "customer". Below is the code I used in method processAuthenticationResponse.

```
Map<ClaimMapping, String> claims = new HashMap<ClaimMapping, String>();
claims.put(ClaimMapping.build("http://wso2.org/claims/role", "http://wso2.org/claims/role", null, false), "customer");

AuthenticatedUser user = AuthenticatedUser.createLocalAuthenticatedUserFromSubjectIdentifier("xxxxxx");
context.setSubject(user);
```

Any guide to implement this correctly is very appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. In addition to my code in custom federated authenticator to assign the role to `http://wso2.org/claims/role` claim, I also need to enable [Just-In-Time provisioning](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Just-In-Time+Provisioning+for+an+Identity+Provider) then the user authenticated by my custom federated authenticator will be created in WSO2 with the specified role.

PS. I still can not make the user authenticated by the custom authenticator having specific role without having to have the user created first in WSO2 via Just-In-Time Provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already have a role called 'customer' in your user store.
What you can do here is implement a custom `UserStoreEventListener` by implementing `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener`. I your component activation you need to register this listener as an osgi service.

```
protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {

    YourListener yourListener =
            new YourListener();
    context.getBundleContext().registerService(
            UserOperationEventListener.class.getName(), yourListener, null);
}
```

You can write this listener by extending `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserOperationEventListener` which is an abstract implementation of this interface.

Then by implementing `postAuthenticate` method, you can add required functionality like follows.

```
import org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserOperationEventListener;

public class YourListener extends AbstractUserOperationEventListener {
public boolean isEnable() {
    //add implementation to this or you can enable always by returning true
}

public int getOrderId() {
    //give the order this listener should executed eg-:120
}

@Override
public boolean doPostAuthenticate(String userName, boolean authenticated,
                                  UserStoreManager userStoreManager) throws UserStoreException {

    userStoreManager.updateRoleListOfUser(userName,new String[0], new String[]{"customer"});
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. However I have tries it and it still does not work. I have debugged and it seems that the method doPostAuthenticate is not get called after I authenticate the user in custom authenticator.

More information. I have role "customer" defined in user store. However, the user name that I authenticated via custom authenticator is not in the user store. (that is why I have to write custom authenticator). Is this the correct approach?

Comment: If the method 'doPostAuthenticate' is not getting called, it should be a issue in your service registration. Check if your listener has registered properly.
Is your user and 'customer' role are in two different user stores? You can't assign a role in different user store to a user in another user store

Comment: Hi Chamila. Sorry my question was not clear. I am trying to write a custom authenticator that authenticate a user via mobile application (similar to OTP that we send a code to user's mobile application and user will have to enter the code back in authentication endpoint login page. If it match then the user is authenticated using mobile number as subject identifier) so the user is not store in any user store. However, I want the authenticated user to have role "customer" since I specify the scope  in APIM that allow for user which has role "customer" only. Is it possible in my scenario? Thanks